# How does this calculate the water transport between crops in the webside?

Tags: atmosphere, humidity, greenhouse-gases, moisture-flux

click->http://gpe.letsgrow.com/
next click->moisture transport

In the results of Moist transport through the crop, what is the relationship between crop height and diffusion, air movement, and total water transport? Are there any formulas between them that can express the relationship?

Comment: This sounds to me more like an agriculture question. I'm not sure that the artificial watering of greenhouse crops is appropriate to Earth Sciences.